# from sql query to hibernate dialect

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, query-builder

I think it's a general question because I'm not an expert. Like a lot of people, I've began to create my first queries by the classical way: select something on something where something = something lol.

Then, I've discovered Spring Boot with Hibernate and the repositories. Everything seems more simple with a getSomethingBySomething();

But now, I would like to find a way to transform some difficult queries into an hibernate/jpa dialect.

For example, it's easy to create a complicated request with tools like query builder (DB Forge or from another editor. Is there a way to obtain the same result but with Hibernate dialect instead of complicated SQL request with inner join and everything?

EDIT:

Here is an exemple of sql query I would like to transform in Hibernate dialect:

```
@Query(nativeQuery =true, value = "select s.*  FROM doc_usecomp \n" +
            "  INNER JOIN document s \n" +
            "    ON doc_usecomp.doc_id = s.doc_id\n" +
            "  INNER JOIN user_company usercomp \n" +
            "    ON doc_usecomp.usercomp_id = usercomp.usercomp_id\n" +
            "  INNER JOIN company c on usercomp.usercomp_id = c.comp_id \n" +
            "WHERE c.comp_city = 'PARIS'")
    List<Document> findAllDocumentByMCity();
```

Seems very difficult to find the documents from all the companies from a city but I have the classical way to do it with sql but with hibernate...

Hope a solution exist!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your SQL. It's a good practice to use derived queries **getSomethingBySomething()** for 1-4 conditions. For more complex queries you can use JPA Criteria API [spring-data-criteria-queries](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries)

Comment: Ok, so here is and example in the first post!